# NSNumberFormatter format float string as integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have an array of strings number with decimal digits, that should be converted in NSNumber:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
    NSArray * ar = @[@"0.0001",@"0.0010",@"0.002", @"0.02"];
    for (NSString * numS in ar) {
        NSNumber * num = [formatter numberFromString:numS];
        NSLog(@"%@", num);
    }
```

The log prints:
*0.0001, 0.001, **2**, 0.02*
I can't understand why this is happening, I've also tried to change fraction digits properties with no success.
When I write a number with 3 fraction digits where the first two are zero, I always get an integer as result.
I'm using the simulator, Xcode 8.
[image]
We had run further tests:

- If we remove the *style*, it works as expected
- The problem exists also on devices
- In playground with swift 3 and the *style*, it works

**[UPDATE]**

I forgot to mention that my device locale is in italian, if I set it in english it works.
Probably set a style and later modify it's decimal separator when the official locale decimal separator doesn't match is not a good idea.
I still do not understand why this only happens for that specific format.

Comment: I've ran your code and what I've got:
        '2017-01-20 18:01:32.121 ZoomingSample[5294:181511] 0.0001

        2017-01-20 18:01:32.122 ZoomingSample[5294:181511] 0.001

        2017-01-20 18:01:32.122 ZoomingSample[5294:181511] 0.002

        2017-01-20 18:01:32.122 ZoomingSample[5294:181511] 0.02'

Comment: you probably misread the output, my friend, your snippet presents this: `0.0001`, `0.001`, `0.002`, and `0.02`.

Comment: added a screenshot as proof

Comment: for sake of completeness on SWIFT 3 in playground works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Italian locale, the `.` is the grouping separator. That should basically tell you everything.

The advice is, set the locale, don't tamper with the specific language settings.

Comment: I was almost writing the answer by myself, thank you.

Comment: @Andrea Heh, so I didn't actually help you :)

Comment: No you did, my colleague came up with the same hypothesis at the same time, you confirmed that, so thanks :)